# jquery bubbling up the dom to see if there is any match to an ID

Tags: jquery

I have a help div that becomes visible, I made it so that if a click is outside the div, it closes the help div.

I want the div to remain open if the user click inside the div.  For regular Javascript, I use the bubbling up code to match the parent's id.  My partial JS code is

```
var click = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
var match = "divid";

while(click.parentNode){
        if(click==match) {
        return;//do nothing
            }//if
```

what is the jquery equivalent to this recursive javascript code?

TIA

edited to avoid confusion.

Comment: So you have an event that will listen for click anywhere on the page, but the problem is that this includes the 'opened' div. You only want to listen on anything EXCEPT this div. Or more accurately, it can listen on the div, but if it hears a click it should do nothing. Is that correct?

Comment: @gregp, yes. If the click is inside the div, then it should not close the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return false and it'll work. Or you could use stopPropagation() which is a utility function built into jQuery:

```
jQuery("#divid").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/W8MfD/

The return false method will still bubble up before returning false, as I understand it.

I do tend to believe that if you anticipate using lots of these kinds of events, you would benefit from using some sort of widget framework. The kind of behaviour you're creating is commonplace and most frameworks already have it. jQuery UI isn't bad (though in my opinion it could be better). There are others out there, too.

Comment: Hi gregp, thanks, I understand that part.  I just want to know how to bubbling up.  Also, that code for some reason does not work properly on the initial load, it works correctly only after it has been run once.

Comment: Always runs first time in the fiddle. I actually prefer using .delegate() instead of .click() to resolve timing, but I just quickly threw it together. As for your question: if you really want to bubble up manually, you don't need jQuery. I guess I missed that from your initial question.